# Send Keys as Special characters

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, webdriver, protractor

How to send the following ^^ inside a user input in protractor?

I used the following code:

```
txtCraBox.sendKeys('\u0302','\u0302')
```

But I do not obtain the desired representation which is the following : ^^

This is the complete test :

```
it('should not accept alphanumeric between carets with no prefix (' + component.name + ')', function() {
    moveComponent(component.componentIdx).then(function() {
      txtCraBox.sendKeys('\u005E', '\u005E')
        .then(function() {
          txtCraBox.click().then(
            function() {
              browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_LEFT).perform().then(
                function() {
                  for (var i = 0; i < alphaNumList.length; i++) {
                    txtCraBox.sendKeys(alphaNumList[i]).then(function() {
                      expect(txtCraBox.getAttribute('value')).toBe('\u005E\u005E');
                      expect($(craBoxCss + '>p').getAttribute('value')).toBe('\u005E\u005E');
                    });
                  }
                });
            });
        });
    });
  });
```

Can someone could help me?

Comment: Don't you have something like predefined constants? Or a method that gets the key from Unicode character ... something like `getKeyFromUnicode('\u0302')` instead of `'\u0302'`.

Comment: sendKeys is able to translate unicode Key but if you have any relevant  method or library .Let me know !

Comment: @engineer sendKeys is able to translate unicode Key but if you have any relevant method or library .Let me know !

Answer (score 0):

It is actually working for me. Here is an example code:

```
describe("Google search", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("https://google.com");

        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.name("q"))), 5000);
    });

    it("should enter unicode characters", function () {
        element(by.name("q")).sendKeys('\u0302', '\u0302').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });
});
```

And here is the screenshot of the Google Search Input during the test:

[image]

---

For the `^^`, you can use:

```
.sendKeys('^^')
```

or:

```
.sendKeys('\u005E', '\u005E')
```

Comment: I obtained  the same result as  your example but I need to obtain the following : ^^

Comment: @user2985176 okay, but why cannot you just use `.sendKeys('^^')`?

Comment: test both solutions result to an empty textbox

Comment: @user2985176 interesting, could you share the link to a website (if it is public) and the complete code you have so far?